# Play only a certain part of a video when a button is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, video

I am setting up a video player on my page, I have made it so that when you click a button it skips to a certain part. This works fine however when it gets to a certain part i would like the video to stop or pause.

I have no clue on where to start with this, but i will put my existing code in:

```
var myvideo = document.getElementById('myvideo'),
                    playbutton = document.getElementById('playme'),
                    jumplink1 = document.getElementById('jump');
                    jumplink2 = document.getElementById('jump1');
                    jumplink3 = document.getElementById('jump2');
                    jumplink4 = document.getElementById('jump3');

                jumplink1.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    myvideo.play();
                    myvideo.pause();
                    myvideo.currentTime = 40.1;
                    myvideo.play();
                }, false);

                 jumplink2.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    myvideo.play();
                    myvideo.pause();
                    myvideo.currentTime = 85;
                    myvideo.play();
                }, false);

<video id="myvideo" width="620">
                  <source src="video/1.William Morrison_short-comp.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
                    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                </video>

                  <p id="play-me-hover">
                      <button id="playme" id="playme">play full interview</button>
                  </p>
                  <p id="jump-hover">
                      <button class="video-button" id="jump">courses</button>
                  </p>

                  <p>
                      <button class="video-button" id="jump1">surgeons</button>
```

Comment: I don't see why just using a `timer()` wouldn't work here if you know the amount of time from the play till when you want to stop is

Comment: Can you go on further please? Sorry i'm new to working with video

Comment: lot of good stuff here. have a look http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/custom-html5-video-player-with-css3-and-jquery/

Comment: also have a look at this. https://github.com/vebersol/jQPlayer/

Comment: and this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Specifying_playback_range